# Looking for manga

Tags: juuhime

I'm looking for a manga where a boy has been sentenced to death and the only way to live is to work for the church that tried him

All I remember is that a high ranking priestess took him in and he uses a gun to do his jobs

Comment: Any idea of the art style or when it's from?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It might be [Juuhime - Sincerely Night](http://myanimelist.net/manga/8237/Juuhime_~Sincerely_Night~). It features a main character that duel wields guns and was sentenced to 500 years of prison by the church. Here's MAL's synopsis:

> Luca Athrason has been sentenced with 500 years of imprisonment – such is the price to pay for his sins. The only way for him to shorten his sentence is to accomplish his missions as the Church’s vanguard or as some might call it... The Church's Dog!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for Chrno Crusade.

Comment: Isn't it Rosette that uses the gun in Chrno Crusade?